# Removing horizontal spaces Between image Columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a hard time with the spaces in the second row, I want to make the images down to add up to the spaces but the stuff isn't working out I have tried other solutions but they did not help.

How can I fix this?

Here is the image of what I am trying to get rid of, the spaces in 2nd row:

[image]

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 pull-right"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail nothing">
        <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" class="image-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail nothing">
        <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" class="image-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail nothing">
        <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" class="image-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

so this is just the code that i used for the columns feel free to look into it 
  pls

Comment: ,you want be images vertically? or want remove space between them?

Comment: If you take a look at the image link on top you will see spaces which suppose to contain two images so i want the images to fit in but it is not so that's the problem@ehsan

Comment: yeah I am using bootstrap@Shiladitya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution to the spaces between clowuns. And this is caused by different image sizes. Here you Go with the solution.

```
<div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
      "your images"
   </div>
</div>
```

**Just add the style to the row.**

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/ynsmy2ku/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 pull-right"> 
      <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail nothing">
            <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" class="image-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail nothing">
            <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" class="image-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail nothing">
            <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" class="image-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>
      
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail nothing">
            <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" class="image-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail nothing">
            <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" class="image-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail nothing">
            <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" class="image-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you want to to remove the space in second row, then rather than having multiple row, have **single row** & use **columns (col-models)** inside.

It will automatically adjust based on space.

Comment: yeah it is working fine but the container goes all the way across the sidebar and it shifts out from the parent container. i appreciate your work but is there any way to solve this cause it makes my work dirty. thanks for the one answered@shiladitya

Comment: If you can share your full code (current messed up code) in a jsFiddle, will definitely help you out.

Comment: I have already Fixed The problem with padding. Shiladitya It goes back to its first problem when the image size varies any help, sorry for taking your time again@Shiladitya